# Signed Production build with a debug keystore

Tags: android, xamarin

By mistake I have signed my production android APK with debug keystore.Is their any way I can change sign it with a new keystore and still manage to give a upgrade.

Also I have deleted the debug.keystore also.

Not much hopeful but if anyone can help.

Comment: It is not possible to sign with a different keystore and keep the same package name. You might have some luck, contacting Google directly.

Answer (score -1):

As pointed out in the docs, it depends : https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing

**If you don't use GooglePlay Signin**, it's not possible.

> if you’re not opted in to app signing with by Google Play and you lose
>   your app’s signing key, you lose the ability to update your app.

**If you don't use GooglePlay Signin** it's possible :

> You keep the upload key and use it to sign your app for upload to the
>   Google Play Store. By using a separate upload key you can request an
>   upload key reset here : https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/7384423#reset